# Flink Scala API "not enough arguments"

Tags: scala-ide, apache-flink

I'm having troubles using Apache Flink Scala API

For example, even when I take the examples from the official documentation, the scala compiler gives me tons of compilation errors.

Code:

```scala
object TestFlink {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
    val text = env.fromElements(
      "Who's there?",
      "I think I hear them. Stand, ho! Who's there?")

    val counts = text.flatMap { _.toLowerCase.split("\\W+") filter { _.nonEmpty } }
      .map { (_, 1) }
      .groupBy(0)
      .sum(1)

    counts.print()

    env.execute("Scala WordCount Example")
  }
}
```

Scala IDE outputs the following for the line `val text = env.fromElements`

```
Multiple markers at this line
  - not enough arguments for method fromElements: (implicit evidence$14: scala.reflect.ClassTag[String], implicit evidence$15: 
   org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.TypeInformation[String])org.apache.flink.api.scala.DataSet[String]. Unspecified value parameter evidence$15.
  - could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.TypeInformation[String]
  - could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.TypeInformation[String]
  - not enough arguments for method fromElements: (implicit evidence$14: scala.reflect.ClassTag[String], implicit evidence$15: 
   org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.TypeInformation[String])org.apache.flink.api.scala.DataSet[String]. Unspecified value parameter evidence$15.
```

It's not just `fromElements` method: even if I read from a file and then try to do something as simple as `ds.map(r => r)`, I get something very similar

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - not enough arguments for method map: (implicit evidence$4: org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.TypeInformation[K], implicit 
     evidence$5: scala.reflect.ClassTag[K])org.apache.flink.api.scala.DataSet[K]. Unspecified value parameters evidence$4, evidence$5.
    - could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.TypeInformation[K]
    - could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.TypeInformation[K]
    - not enough arguments for method map: (implicit evidence$4: org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.TypeInformation[K], implicit 
     evidence$5: scala.reflect.ClassTag[K])org.apache.flink.api.scala.DataSet[K]. Unspecified value parameters evidence$4, evidence$5.
```

I tried two versions of Flink: 0.8.1 from Maven Central and the most fresh one from the github repository.

I'm running Windows 7, scala 2.10.4, jdk 1.7.0_25, Scala IDE version is  3.0.3-20140327-1716-Typesafe on top of Eclipse 4.3.0

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You need to add the following import to your code:

```
import org.apache.flink.api.scala._
```

Then the example works.

Comment: Thanks Robert. While it does solve the described problems, I still have other issues with generic parameters. Could you please have a look at a follow-up here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29542214

Comment: I forwarded the question ... ;)