# Flink Scala API functions on generic parameters

Tags: apache-flink

It's a follow up question on [Flink Scala API "not enough arguments"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29540121/flink-scala-api-not-enough-arguments).

I'd like to be able to pass Flink's `DataSet`s around and do something with it, but the parameters to the dataset are generic.

Here's the problem I have now:

```scala
import org.apache.flink.api.scala.ExecutionEnvironment
import org.apache.flink.api.scala._
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

object TestFlink {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
    val text = env.fromElements(
      "Who's there?",
      "I think I hear them. Stand, ho! Who's there?")

    val split = text.flatMap { _.toLowerCase.split("\\W+") filter { _.nonEmpty } }
    id(split).print()

    env.execute()
  }

  def id[K: ClassTag](ds: DataSet[K]): DataSet[K] = ds.map(r => r)
}
```

I have this error for `ds.map(r => r)`:

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - not enough arguments for method map: (implicit evidence$256: org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.TypeInformation[K], implicit 
     evidence$257: scala.reflect.ClassTag[K])org.apache.flink.api.scala.DataSet[K]. Unspecified value parameters evidence$256, evidence$257.
    - not enough arguments for method map: (implicit evidence$4: org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.TypeInformation[K], implicit evidence
     $5: scala.reflect.ClassTag[K])org.apache.flink.api.scala.DataSet[K]. Unspecified value parameters evidence$4, evidence$5.
    - could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.TypeInformation[K]
```

Of course, the `id` function here is just an example, and I'd like to be able to do something more complex with it.

How it can be solved?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you also need to have TypeInformation as a context bound on the K parameter, so:

```scala
def id[K: ClassTag: TypeInformation](ds: DataSet[K]): DataSet[K] = ds.map(r => r)
```

The reason is, that Flink analyses the types that you use in your program and creates a TypeInformation instance for each type you use. If you want to create generic operations then you need to make sure a TypeInformation of that type is available by adding a context bound. This way, the Scala compiler will make sure an instance is available at the call site of the generic function.