# Apache Flink Streaming type mismatch in flatMap function

Tags: scala, apache-flink, flink-streaming

Trying to use streaming api of 0.10.0 flink version in scala 2.10.4. While trying to compile this first version:

```scala
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.DataStream
import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.windowing.time._

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
    val text = env.socketTextStream("localhost", 9999)

    val words : DataStream[String] = text.flatMap[String](
      new Function[String,TraversableOnce[String]] { 
        def apply(line:String):TraversableOnce[String] = line.split(" ")
      })

    env.execute("Window Stream wordcount")
  }
}
```

I am getting compile time error:

```
[error]  found   : String => TraversableOnce[String]
[error]  required: org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.FlatMapFunction[String,String]
[error]       new Function[String,TraversableOnce[String]] { def apply(line:String):TraversableOnce[String] = line.split(" ")})
[error]       ^
```

And in decompiled version of DataStream.class that I have included to project there are functions that accept such type (the last one):

```java
public <R> DataStream<R> flatMap(FlatMapFunction<T, R> flatMapper, TypeInformation<R> evidence$12, ClassTag<R> evidence$13) {
        if (flatMapper == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("FlatMap function must not be null.");
        }
        TypeInformation outType = (TypeInformation)Predef..MODULE$.implicitly(evidence$12);
        return package..MODULE$.javaToScalaStream((org.apache.flink.streaming.api.datastream.DataStream)this.javaStream.flatMap(flatMapper).returns(outType));
    }

    public <R> DataStream<R> flatMap(Function2<T, Collector<R>, BoxedUnit> fun, TypeInformation<R> evidence$14, ClassTag<R> evidence$15) {
        if (fun == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("FlatMap function must not be null.");
        }
        Function2<T, Collector<R>, BoxedUnit> cleanFun = this.clean((F)fun);
        .anon flatMapper = new /* Unavailable Anonymous Inner Class!! */;
        return this.flatMap((FlatMapFunction<T, R>)flatMapper, evidence$14, evidence$15);
    }

    public <R> DataStream<R> flatMap(Function1<T, TraversableOnce<R>> fun, TypeInformation<R> evidence$16, ClassTag<R> evidence$17) {
        if (fun == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("FlatMap function must not be null.");
        }
        Function1<T, TraversableOnce<R>> cleanFun = this.clean((F)fun);
        .anon flatMapper = new /* Unavailable Anonymous Inner Class!! */;
        return this.flatMap((FlatMapFunction<T, R>)flatMapper, evidence$16, evidence$17);
    }
```

What could be wrong here? I would be grateful if you could give some insight.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is that you are importing the Java `StreamExecutionEnvironment` of Flink: `org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment`.

You have to use the Scala variant of the `StreamExecutionEnvironment` like this: `import org.apache.flink.streaming.api.scala.StreamExecutionEnvironment`.
With that change, everything is successfully building!

**Original answer:**
The problem is that you are passing a `Function` to the `flatMap()` method. However `flatMap()` expects a `FlatMapFunction`.

```
 val words : DataStream[String] = text.flatMap[String](
      new FlatMapFunction[String,String] {
        override def flatMap(t: String, collector: Collector[String]): Unit = t.split(" ")
      })
```

Comment: Yes. This lines compile. What I tried in the code above is to satisfy "flatMap(Function1<T, TraversableOnce<R>> fun, ..." types. I looked here http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/anonymous-function-syntax.html and saw that (x: Int) => x + 1 is a shorthand for "new Function1[Int, Int] ...".

Comment: Before trying that I have tried to compile https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-0.10/apis/streaming_guide.html#example-program for Scala which resulted in a missing type parameter for anonymous function.

Comment: For the example from the flink documentation to work, you need to add the following import statement `import org.apache.flink.api.scala._`.

Comment: I have added this import after looking your answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29540121/flink-scala-api-not-enough-arguments?lq=1 , although there was no effect. The error was "missing parameter type [error]     val words = text.flatMap{ x => x.split(" ")}".

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question, but which code are you trying to run? 
Are you starting Flink out of your IDE? Which scala library version did you configure in your IDE?

Comment: I am trying to run first example from https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-0.10/apis/streaming_guide.html for scala. This is an sbt project. libraryDependencies ++= Seq("org.apache.flink" % "flink-streaming-scala" % "0.10.0"). scalaVersion := "2.11.7" and "2.10.4" - with the same error. I do not use IDE - only notepad.

Comment: When using the `flink-streaming-scala` dependency, you have to use scala version `2.10.4`. If you want to use scala 2.11, you have to use `link-streaming-scala_2.11`
Can you maybe post the entire project (sbt build file, source, ...) on github? I suspect its a small issue, but fixing it like this doesn't seem very productive.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95378/discussion-between-rmetzger-and-user2244092).